# How to include PHP $_SESSION values in a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, php, session

I use `$_SESSION['siteRoot']` to store the root address of my website in (it's basically a framework so this can change depending on the URL used to access the site).  I need to use this value in some of my javascript files...

Up until now I've been including my js files as `.php`, and putting the following code at the top of my `js` files, like so:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/javascript");
    session_start();
?>
```

This has been working fine on my **local-host** for testing - but when I upload it to the live server I noticed that my session was being reset every time I reload the page, and after a day of debugging finally discover that it's the session_start(); line in my java-script files that is causing this behavior.

I've tried the following:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION))
    {
    session_start();
    }

if (session_id() == '')
    {
    session_start();
    }

if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
    {
    session_start();
    }
```

and also just leaving out the session_start altogether.  If I don't start the session then I can't use the variables (obviously...), but I can't find a way of starting it that doesn't wipe the session I already created in my main page.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like this isn't related to your creating a JS file. Maybe remove the JS bit unless you think it's relevant?

Comment: `session_start()` creates a new session or _resumes an existing one_. When you have an existing session, `session_start()` will not clear or overwrite it. If you see new sessions being created with each page load, and you have ruled out the possibility that your script is unexpectedly destroying the session elsewhere, there is a problem with the server's session handling, not the script.

Comment: Goikiu - this doesn't work.  My session is still reset.George - this is what I assumed since it works on one server and not on the other - do you have any advice on how I could debug something like that?

Comment: have you seen if there are differences on the two enviroment (localhost and web server) ?

Comment: When I ran phpinfo() I did notice that session save path is set to "no value" - do I need to change this?

Comment: it may be relevant @user3640967 , try to search about it

Comment: Never mind, something just struck me and I worked it out - I'll post it as an answer in case anyone else has the same problem.  Thanks for taking the time to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not caused by the session itself exactly, but because I hadn't included my class autoloader before calling the session, and so my custom classes were not surviving the deserialize process (even though it's a javascript file and I don't use any of said classes!)

I changed my javascript code to:

```
<?php
    include ('include/autoloader.php');
    header("Content-type: application/javascript");
    session_start();
?>
```

and everything works fine.  Easy to forget when you're not using any of the serialized classes on that page!